# Android sdk: tools\android.bat the system can't find the file specified

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk-2.1

I just downloaded android SDK manager (again...) and installed it on my machine, because I want to use Adnroid Studio. I also installed JAVA JDK (8.0.31). `java -version` command in cmd returns:

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

When I try to run android SDK manager I get the message:

```
   Failed to execute tools\android.bat:,error 2 
   The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Also, when I run the AVD manager I get the error:

```
 Failed to execute tools\android.bat:, error 5
 Access id denied.
```

I made sure that the `android.bat` file exists in the `tools` folder, tried to run it directly as an Admin, but it didn't help.
I used the `call` command in CMD to run android.bat, and this is what I get:
[image]

It was working for me a few month ago, but I don't understand what has changed...
I searched the web for an answer, but couldn't find one. I'm losing hope.
so, if you you can help, I will be grateful.
Thanks!

Comment: What folder is `android.bat` in?

Comment: i guess you try to run 32-bit sdk on 64-bit os.

Comment: In the `tools` folder. I also tried moving it to the root folder, but that didn't help. P.S. notice the edit above.

Comment: Have you defined the `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable to point towards your JDK directory?

Comment: `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31`. is that what it should be?

Comment: I downloaded the sdk from [link]http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html[link] under the option sdk tools only -> windows

Comment: Yep, something like that. Make sure its a system environmental variable as well in that opening a blank cmd window and typing `echo %JAVA_HOME%` should result in the full path being echoed.

Comment: I did it and is shows `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31` is thak OK?

Comment: After looking into the `find_java.bat` file which `android.bat` calls, it seems that it can't detect your system's architecture correctly. Try running `reg query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0"` directly from the command line and see what pops up. If its an access denied message that'll be your culprit.

Comment: is show some keys. what should I be looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70484/discussion-between-cpu-terminator-and-789).